# asigning ids in kivy on the python side

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

im using kivy. the what im trying to do is have and 'idea',a slider and a label containing the slider's current value in a row in a grid layout

now getting the layout is fine but getting the label to have a text value the same as the slider's current value is tricky. I'm trying to use string concation to refer to the label with the same number suffix as the slider that it is paired with.

I think the problem im having is that im trying to assign ids on the python side when they normally have to be done on the kv side. It's either that or the fact the ids i'm assigning are strings when kv would normally expect plain text. any help would be appreciated

```
class ScatterTextWidget(FloatLayout):
        def run_me(self):
            r=1 
            main_list=self.ids.main_list
            main_list.clear_widgets()
            main_list.height=0
            for idea in imported_ideas:     
                main_list.add_widget(Label(text=idea,color=(0,0,0,1),id='idea_label_'+str(r)))
                main_list.add_widget(Slider(id='Slider_'+str(r),min=0,max=10,value=5, step=1,on_value_pos=self.slider_slid(self)))
                main_list.add_widget(Label(color=(0,0,0,1),id='value_label_'+str(r)))

                value_label=self.ids['value_label_'+str(r)] # get this working and then apply the method into slider slid
                value_label.text='xxx'

                main_list.height+=35                

                r +=1
            button_1=self.ids.button_1
            button_1.text='Begin'
            button_1.bind(on_press=self.begin)

        def slider_slid(self,sender):

            s=str(sender.id)

            value_label=self.ids['value_label_'+str(s[12:])]
            value_label.text=str(sender.value)
```

value_label=self.ids['value_label_'+str(s[12:])]
 KeyError: 'value_label_'

Answer (score 2):

`self.ids` only collects ids from children in the kv language rule of the widget. It doesn't know about widgets you added via python.

You don't need to use the id though. In this case you could keep e.g. a dictionary of id -> widget keys.

```
self.keys_dict = {}
for idea in imported_ideas:     
    new_widget = Label(color=(0,0,0,1),id='value_label_'+str(r)))
    main_list.add_widget(new_widget)
    self.keys_dict['value_label_' + str(r)] = new_widget
```

Then later you can access it with `self.keys_dict['value_label_' + str(s[12:])]` or whatever you like.

I suppose in practice you could also modify the actual ids dictionary in the same way, though I subjectively feel it is preferable to maintain your own dictionary with a name that represents its more specific contents.

Comment: Thank you!! im now having new problem, each of the sliders that i have made has the event dispatch on_value=slider_slid slider_slid is a function that uses your lovely dictionary method give a slider's value to the label to display as text. however in order to get the pairing right it needs to know which slider sent it(slider_1,slider_2 etc.), how can i do this?                                im finding it tricky because event dispatches cant take arguments.

Comment: I solved the above problem when I realised that the dispatch function hands over the sending object as an argument,  so by inverting the dictionary I made I could then get the string name of the sending object (in this case a slider) from the string name I could slice and get the number :) thank you very much.