# How to call a kivy widget that was made iteratively

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

Hi I have code that is similar to this

test.kv

```
<SomeWidget>:
    Button:
        text:'Begin'
        pos:(0,0)
        on_press:root.run_me()
    GridLayout:
        iD: grid_layout
        cols:3
```

main.py

```
class SomeWidget(FloatLayout):
        def run_me(self):
            r=1 
            grid_layout=self.ids.grid_layout
            for i in array_of_strings:      
                   grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text=i,id='idea_label_'+str(r)))
                   grid_layout.add_widget(Slider(on_value=slider_slid(self),id='Slider_'+str(r)))
                   grid_layout.add_widget(Label(id='value_label_'+str(r)))
                   r+=1
            value_label=self.ids['value_label_'+str(r)] # this line does not seem to work
            value_label.text='this is the last label: number '+str(r)
```

Here i am generating a label with text 'i', a slider with a tied event, and another label that i want to do something with later on. Since I want to refer to these widgets elsewhere in the code i have attempted to give them each a unique id eg 'idea_label_'+str(r): r+=1 but when i try to refer back to with some_var=self.ids['idea_label_'+str(r)] it doesnt work

I have a feeling that it is either because i am assigning the ids incorrectly , or that ids cannot be assigned from the python side, only the .kv side

is there a better way, or another way, of making widgets in a for loop, in a way that allows for refrencing elsewhere in the code

Comment: If you do just `print self.ids` what does it print?

Comment: It looks like you asked basically the same question twice, I answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130700/asigning-ids-in-kivy-on-the-python-side).